# Post Quantum Cryptography - Verifying if there are no backdoors in these selected algorithms: crystals-kyber, crystals-dilithium, falcon, sphincs+

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, backdoors

I was looking through https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/post-quantum-cryptography/selected-algorithms-2022

How can one begin to mathematically verify if there are no backdoors to these selected post quantum algorithms?

Comment: By starting to analyze them....

Comment: Depending on how paranoid you are, don't forget the random number generator, compiler, operating system, ...